# CSS in HTML mail, it is displayed on the phone but not in the browser?

Tags: html, css, email, templates

I'm working again with a site that send emails, in this case I send an email with CSS style but the problem is the Style only render on phone device and not render on gmail or outlook through browser.

I now that the tag link is not the best way to do that, so I have CSS embeded on the style tag, in this way in others mail code works perfectly.

Another things to says is that resources like images show perfectly trough render code.
I expected that the css shows normally too.

I'm working with CSS3, HTML5 and Codeigniter (an old version, dont rebember which...sorry)

Comment: Can you provide an example of some html that doesn't work?

Comment: Hi, this is an example that html that work in old code and phone but doesn't work on inbox on browser.

`<div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
    <a href="https://twitter.com/" class="fa fa-twitter"></a>
    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/" class="fa fa-instagram"></a>
   </div>`

Comment: Firstly, you need to be using tables as they are more reliable. https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/2019/04/tables-in-html-emails-nesting/